# I attended an interview, but got an email saying I did not attend

Tags: interviewing

I was selected for a face to face interview for a MNC company and attended the interview.

The interview went well and HR told me to wait for 3-4 days.  However, after 3-4 days I have received an email saying that I didn't attend the interview :(

I replied and pointed out the error, but I have not received a response in a week.

What should I do now?

Comment: So they sent an email and you have responded - and now you are awaiting their response? For how long have you waited?

Comment: around one week. Should i wait more?

Comment: No! Like @Lilienthal said you'll actually need to get hold of them immediately. If you have any phone number at all, now is the time to call. Do not send an email again.

Comment: ok but I dont have any contact number. they are giant and all the time I was getting a computer generated emails :( I should go to meet them again thats the only thing I can do

Comment: You will need to find a phone number or a different email address. I assume you have searched their web site. The point is, you must do something else - as the email you replied to could be an un-monitored account. But you really need to take action immediately - even if it means phoning a company main number.

Comment: @morsor sure Ill find a number and try to call them. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @rishiv3 Updated my answer with general phone guidelines in case you need them. Good luck getting this sorted.

Comment: @rishiv3 You're quite welcome. Keep in mind that we discourage accepting an answer too early. You may want to uncheck the acceptance tick and wait 24-48 hours to give others a chance to weigh in and then accept the answer that you found most useful.

Comment: yes, I totally agree :)

Comment: @rishiv3: I edited the question to clean up the grammar a bit. I tried to avoid changing the meaning. However, if I did (change the meaning), or you just don't like the changes, you can [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/64763/edit) it to rollback my changes or make your own.

Comment: @GreenMatt yes, its looking much better now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: the one time that this happened to me the HR person in question had sent the message to all of the interviewees (or so I was told) and I had a second interview a few weeks later. Sometimes the "reply all" button is just too tempting it seems.

Comment: I'm taking a different unpopular approach: look for another position. Clearly something is messed up there and what if they "forgot" your pay raise? Review? etc.

Comment: @MD-Tech it seems like same thing is happening with me, i think. but i havent received any email confirming this error till now

Comment: For things like these you call immediately (right after sending an email) to sort it out.  It is not a small error but an error that could cost you the job.  Playing email-tag games is out, you have to escalate to a phone-tag.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Email them? I'm not sure what's keeping you from just clarifing the issue, which sounds like an obvious clerical error.

> Dear [name of your HR contact / the hiring manager]
>
> I enjoyed getting the chance to meet with [you / hiring manager / interviewer ] [last week / whenever]. I was surprised that I got the below message today stating that I hadn't attended the interview, can I safely ignore this? I'd rather not be dropped from consideration due to an administrative error.
>
> Kind regards, [your name]

If you didn't get a response within one or two business days, you'll want to either email someone you spoke to directly, preferably the hiring manager, or you'll want to pick up the phone and call them. You want to avoid being dropped from the running due to a simple mistake and they might move the process along without you if you don't correct this as soon as possible.

Since telephone etiquette and practices are less common these days: in cases where you need to reach someone but don't have a phone number you first check the website to see if they have contact details listed for their HR department or recruitment team. Almost no companies will, but they *will* list a general number that typically goes to the reception. Ask to be transferred to the HR person or hiring manager that you interviewed with or who is processing your application. In case they're being stubborn and won't connect you to people directly, just ask to be transferred to the HR department.

Comment: thanks for answering, I did but not getting any response from them :( thats why i asked here

Comment: And why didn't you mention this rather important fact in your question?

Comment: @rishiv3 That's pretty important information to mention. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Im really sorry i forgot to add this information. thanks i have updated my question. and really sorry for inconvenience

Comment: And you tried calling them?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Unfortunately no, Because I dont have their contact numbers :( but Ill try to visit them

Comment: @rishiv3 While this depends on the type of job, any office-based workplace will not appreciate you dropping in unannounced. See [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44020/is-visiting-a-company-and-approaching-current-employees-an-effective-way-to-get/44040#44040). Try the internet, your previous email exchange (phone numbers are typically in the signature) or the yellow pages if you don't have a phone number.

Answer (score 15):

The unlikely explanation: They don't want you, and this is a lame excuse. Very unlikely, because it would be a lame excuse and completely unnecessary.

Likely explanation: Someone made a mistake. Maybe the interviewer forgot to drop his notes at HR, HR thinks no notes = no interview. No interview = no job. So if you don't act, you won't get a job. And they made a mistake, so it's time to act and to act quickly.

Write down when your interview was, and who interviewed you, if possible with some detail what they asked you. Call the company, ask to be connected to HR, if that doesn't work insist on being connected to HR, and very importantly *don't be sorry for any inconvenience*.

You start the conversation with "I had an interview last Wednesday (for example) that went very well but now I've received an email saying that I missed my interview. Can you sort this out? " And as soon as possible, because once the job is gone, it's gone.

Comment: It's also entirely possible that their HR system just erroneously generated the e-mail. I've received some bizarre e-mails (and letters) from HR systems (and college admissions systems) over the years. Among the most amusing were an e-mail apologizing that I was no longer being considered for a position (a position for which I had declined the offer they made me...) and an acceptance letter from a graduate school on the second day of classes after I had withdrawn my application several months earlier.

Comment: That said, I completely agree that OP needs to contact them quickly and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Of course, it's entirely possible that the "lame excuse" is a way to avoid anti-discriminatory laws or something like that.

Comment: @Luaan: *Some* lame excuses might serve such a purpose, but not this one, seeing as it's a bizarre and blatant lie about an objective fact that the candidate is privy to.

Comment: @ruakh Well, that sounds like the definition of discrimination to me : )

Comment: @nocomprende: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. Are you saying that "failing miserably at hiding one's discrimination" is the definition of discrimination?

Comment: Or someone didn't want to hire you but didn't want to say so so they lost your interview.

Comment: @ruakh "*a bizarre and blatant lie about an objective fact that the candidate is privy to.*" That is the definition of Prejudice: "preconceived opinion that is not based on reason or actual experience." I was just slightly off. But you nailed it. A wrong opinion that leads to action becomes a lie.

Comment: @nocomprende: Sorry, I think you must have completely misunderstood my original comment, and indeed, this entire page. Luaan is suggesting that the company may be intentionally pretending that the OP did not attend the interview, when in fact (s)he did, in order to conceal their (unrelated) discriminatory desire not to hire him/her.